# Devise(1.3.4 ownward),Omniauth to use ldap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

I want to use Devise(1.3.4) in a scenario at first it check login details over LDAP through Omniauth if that unsuccessful than it try database verifcation can you please guide me with example to do this task thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful example apps with Devise with scenarios:
https://github.com/RailsApps

You might wanna see this:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber